# Check validity of cached HTTP response

Tags: ios, swift, validation, caching, nsurlsession

Using the `URLSession` family of classes, is there a way to check the validity of a response? Specifically, I have an HTTP response whose `Cache-Control` header specifies `no-cache`, so that any cached response will have to be submitted for validation before it can be used. I can retrieve the `CachedURLResponse` object from `URLCache.shared`, but none of `URLSession`, `URLCache`, or `CachedURLResponse` seem to have any methods for determining whether such a cached response is still valid. Such methods are also absent from `URLSessionDelegate` and `URLSessionTaskDelegate`.

Is there any way to do this other than initiating the actual validation request myself? Presumably this is done somewhere in the `URLSession` stack (although I'm not sure of this), but it looks as if this functionality may just not be exposed by the public API.

Answer (score 2):

The question is why do you need to check the validity. If you want only to check the validity you may use a probably uncommon method by using `URLProtocol` and writing a custom [`NSURLProtocolClient`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlprotocolclient). The client has only empty methods except:

```
func urlProtocol(_ protocol: URLProtocol, cachedResponseIsValid cachedResponse: CachedURLResponse) {
    // Cached response is valid. Store this information in a appropriate way.
    protocol.stopLoading()
}
```

Now, you create a protocol with that client

```
let myClient = ...
let protocol = NSURLProtocol(request, cachedResponse, client: myClient)

protocol.startLoading()
protocol.stopLoading() // Stop, if urlProtocol(_: cachedResponseIsValid:) was not called
```

Comment: This won’t work—the cached response will happily be stored in the temporaryCache and be retrieved. We don’t know whether the cached response is valid until we request the page again and possibly receive a ‘not modified’ response.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the caching of an HTTP response is handled automatically. (Just to be sure, I tried it again just before answering this question).

The default caching policy on a `URLRequest` is `useProtocolCachePolicy`. So, on all the subsequent requests to that url, the HTTP headers will contain the `If-None-Match` key, with the latest `Etag` as its value.

If this is not working for you automatically, make sure that the server is sending the `Etag` header in its response. Also, that the server acknowledges the `If-None-Match` header on all the requests.

**TL;DR**

*CHECK:*

1. That you get the `Cache-Control` and the `Etag` header in your
   responses from the server.
2. That the server receives an `If-None-Match` header with the
   correct `Etag` value, in all the subsequent requests.
3. That the server is actually configured to handle the cached
   responses (As in, it responds to the `If-None-Match` header
   correctly).

**References:**

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest.cachepolicy
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ios-network-caching-http-headers